# Asymmetric graphs where all adjacent vertices have different degree

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry, conjectures

I conjecture the following :

If $G$ is a graph so that every pair of adjacent vertices have different degree, then $G$ is not asymmetric graph.
I will remind that a graph is a asymmetric if there are no automorphisms, except for the trivial automorphisms.

It is possible that this statement is incorrect.
Can someone find a counterexample?

And a similar conjecture:

If $G$ is a $2$-connected chordal graph, then it contains a triangle where at least two vertices are of the same degree.

Comment: It seems pretty unlikely to me.  If the graph is large, it ought to be possible to modify its periphery to eliminate any automorphisms, while still preserving the condition that adjacent vertices always have different degree.  What led you to conjecture this?  Why do you think it seems plausible?

Comment: I was just trying to draw graphs with different degrees for adjacent vertices. And I noticed that when I started without a clear plan, it seemed impossible to correct it to a graph with the desired property. Every time I solve a violation, a new one arises. I then thought about the graphs that did have the property and they all had a symmetrical structure. Have you also looked at the second conjecture? If you try to draw a counterexample, you get what I mean, you get stuck in an endless loop of correcting violations. I'm more convinced of the second conjecture tbh

Comment: This site works with **one question per post.** Please make a separate post for the second question.

Answer (score 1):

$K_1$ is an asymmetric graph in which adjacent vertices have different degrees. Here is a less trivial example.

Start with an asymmetric tree $T$ with degree sequence $3,2,2,2,1,1,1$.

The complement of $T$ is an asymmetric graph $\overline T$ with degree sequence $5,5,5,4,4,4,3$.

Subdividing each edge of $\overline T$, we get an asymmetric bipartite graph $G$ with degree sequence $5,5,5,4,4,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2$ in which each edge joins a vertex of degree $2$ to a vertex of degree $\ge3$.

Here's a smaller example: take a path with vertices $v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6$ and edges $v_0v_1,v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5,v_5v_6$, and add two more edges $v_1v_3$ and $v_1v_5$.